# "In the flesh" for things

Tags: phrase-requests, adjectives

When we meet someone we have only heard about before, our impressions of them may be confirmed or be revised.  We can say, after meeting them, that they are different *in the flesh* (i.e. compared to the impressions we had).

Is there an equivalent phrase to "*in the flesh*" for things?  For example:

> I knew this painting from seeing it in books.  The colours are surprisingly dull when you see them ***in the flesh***.

Comment: I have heard “in the flesh” used for things. No references, so not @n answer.

Comment: "I saw the Empire State Building in the flesh" - it seems you are asking something like "the building is not made of flesh so how". On the one hand the speaker may be referring metaphorically to the physical material of the object, but on the other, he may be referring to his own flesh and its proximity to the building. ... Either works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***In the flesh*** is very much alright. The Royal Academy of Arts uses it:

> Is it essential to see a painting ***in the flesh***? ([RoyalAc](https://www.royalacademy.org.uk/article/debate-in-the-flesh))

There is another statement in that debate, that expresses it differently:

> Paintings can only reveal themselves if we ***commune with them in person***, argues artist Emyr Williams.

[OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=in%20the%20flesh%20meaning&sca_esv=565644944&ei=01oEZdvJGJOki-gPsbieqAY&oq=in%20the%20flesh%20meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFGluIHRoZSBmbGVzaCBtZWFuaW5nKgIIADIIEAAYigUYkQIyBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgUQABiABDIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMggQABgHGB4YDzIGEAAYBxgeSOwbUABYxQ5wAHgBkAEAmAGaA6AByRaqAQgyLTExLjAuMbgBAcgBAPgBAcICCBAAGIAEGLED4gMEGAAgQYgGAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1) (sorry for the Google link, but have no other access) defines the idiom ***in the flesh*** as meaning:

> in person or (***of a thing***) *in its actual state*.

On the other hand, ***in the flesh*** can also refer to the person "doing the seeing". (see [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/in%20the%20flesh))

Comment: Yes; we really do need a better way to link to 'Oxford Languages [Dictionary] courtesy of Google'.

Comment: @fev - yes, I think your last point is why in person doesn't sound right to me. 'In the flesh' for me refers to the person you are talking about - their fleshy presence that is in front of you.  'In person', on the other hand,  refers not to the person/thing of interest but to you, the observer.

Comment: It's looking like (the ironic usage of) in the flesh for things is the best I'm going to get.

Comment: I think you are safe using it, Dan.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. I'm not convinced that "in the flesh" refers to the painting in your first example – I think it means "in person". Even if using "in the flesh" for a painting is acceptable, it's not *very much* all right. It sounds quite strange to me.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, for things, you can use the phrase "**in person**" or "**in real life.**"

For example:

> The colors are surprisingly dull when you see them in person.

> **in person**
>
> With one's own body and physical presence; not through media, a representative, or indirectly.
> Synonyms: *face to face*, *in the flesh*, *vis-à-vis*
>
> - *Have you ever seen a celebrity in person?*
> - *He had seen the burger on TV, but in person it looked so much juicier.*
>
> [[Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_person#:%7E:text=With%20one%27s%20own%20body%20and,seen%20a%20celebrity%20in%20person%3F)

Comment: Yes, and in that case **in person** refers to you being present where it is.

Comment: *In real life* is close.   The trouble is the image of the painting in the book is, arguably, also 'real life' (i.e. what is real life!!  Usually 'real life' is in contrast to 'fiction') ...

Answer (score 2):

You could always put it in terms of seeing *the original*.

Comment: Yes, although I was hoping for a more colourful metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **face to face** (sometimes hyphenated). [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+face+to+face+with+something) has

> **come face to face with (someone or something)**
> To confront or encounter someone or something directly.
>
> *I was gradually being brought face to face with the fact that I had failed.*
> *Training for a marathon has forced me to come face to face with my physical limitations.*
> *I had been trying to avoid my math teacher, but then I came face to face with her in the cafeteria.*

So the sentences could be

> After meeting __ they are different face to face (compared to the impressions we had).

> The colours are surprisingly dull when you see the painting face to face.

Comment: This works, but it is just as much of a metaphor as "in the flesh" if the item in question doesn't have a face :)

Answer (score 1):

**in actuality**

*actuality* ([OL&G](https://search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E210US1441G0&p=actuality))

> actual existence, typically as contrasted with what was intended,
> expected, or believed:
> "the building looked as impressive in actuality as it did in magazines"

Comment: Nice word... not sure if it would be widely understood with this meaning.

Comment: @Dan - It basically means *in real life* whereas *IRL* usually means not on FB or social media now.